# excel vba to copy row with activex button

Tags: vba, excel

I am not expert in excel so not sure how to achieve this.

I am having a requirement where. there will be a button (Add button) which will add a new row.
this existing sheet contains the rows with data and on Column A there is an ActiveX button (validate button - there is a code against each of this button).

So while I will click Add button it will add a row on the bottom with an Activex button(validate button) in the column A and the code against it in the back end.

could you please let me know how I can achieve this?

sample image of the excel sheet: https://ibb.co/cijovv

The code I have written which only adds a row but not able to copy the ActiveX button on column A and the code at the backend.

Add row code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Lr As Integer
Dim newLr As Integer
Dim lim As String

Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A
newLr = Lr + 1
lim = "B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(newLr).Insert
'Range(lim).ClearContents
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Would each of the rows validated the same?

Comment: @Romel Geluz yes. code for the validate button will automatically update the column D, E against each row. the same code will be there but it will only update the respected row.

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Comment: Is there a reason behind using ActiveX Controls instead of Form Controls?  If it doesn't really matter which control you use, all you have to do is inserting a button (from Form Controls) to desired location and assign a macro (the code against it in the back end with your term) to it. When you run your code without changing anything, the button and the macro assigned to it will be copied as well.

Comment: anything will be fine for me to achieve this. if you let me know the alternate solution and how to do that ?

Comment: Why not move the button with the activecell? Then make the macro that button is calling dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

1-Insert a Button from Form Control to Cell A5

[image]

2-Get your validate code in a sub (you can name it whatever you like)

```
Sub MyValidateButtonCode() 
'here goes your validate button code 
MsgBox "It works!" 
End Sub
```

3-Assign your macro to the button in Cell A5

[image]
[image]

4-Click CommandButton1 (Add Row Button) and run the above mentioned code to copy rows.

Comment: I tried this, but still, I am not able to copy the button. Rest of the things it's copying except button column A.

Comment: I have used the below to copy it but got another issue. Not able to change the name property of the button from 'validate' to something else on the new row.                                     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(sht).Shapes("validate").Copy
    Sheets(sht).Activate
    Sheets(sht).Range(rng).Select
    Sheets(sht).Paste
    Sheets(sht).Shapes("validate").Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = btn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: @iamnew Do not change your copying code. It works fine. If you cannot make the button get copied try this: Right click the button and select Cut. Then click Cell A5, right click on it and select paste. Then try your code again.